# Check if route exists in Symfony 4

Tags: php, symfony, routes, symfony4, php-7

How can I test whether a given route exists in Symfony 4 by using the route name.

**routes.yaml**

```
home:
  path: /
  controller: App\Controller\Home::index
  methods: [GET]

login:
  path: /login
  controller: App\Controller\Login::index
  methods: [GET]
```

**Controller** (making up an `exists()` method here)

```
$routes->exists('home'); // true
$routes->exists('login'); // true
$routes->exists('foo'); // false
```

Answer (score 5):

From the [Symfony 4 Documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/routing.html#checking-if-a-route-exists)...

> **Check if a Route Exists**
>
> In highly dynamic applications, it may be necessary to check whether a route exists before using it to generate a URL. In those cases, don't use the getRouteCollection() method because that regenerates the routing cache and slows down the application.
>
> Instead, try to generate the URL and catch the RouteNotFoundException thrown when the route doesn't exist:
>
> ```
> use Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\RouteNotFoundException;
>
> // ...
>
> try {
>     $url = $generator->generate($dynamicRouteName, $parameters);
> } catch (RouteNotFoundException $e) {
>     // the route is not defined...
> }
> ```

You can put that code inside a function and return whatever you need.

Comment: I saw this but `$generator` requires that I instantiate `new UrlGenerator($routes, $context)` which takes `$routes` and `$context` where `$routes` is an instance of `new RouteCollection()` so Im kinda back to square one

Comment: The exception trick should work for any of the router functions.  So from a controller just use $this->generateUrl($routeName) and catch any exception.  Of course using exceptions for branching is not very performant.  But once per request will probably be okay.  You could always try digging into the router code and see what the names are stored.  Maybe extend the router generator and add you own find method if need be.

Comment: @yevg The url generator can be typehinted via `Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGeneratorInterface` and injected via dependency injection to the constructor of every service, controller you use if you are using autowiring or you can set the argument to the `router` service.